# Intellij idea input

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%-15s%03d\n", s1, x);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

here is a input:

```
java 10
cpp 65
python 50
```

the output is this,

```
java           010
cpp            065
python         050
```

When I run the program and copy the input to console,there is two case.
when the cursor is after 50 and i copy this whole input the program prints first two lines of ouput and waits for me to push the enter button.Then it gives the third line of output.
But when the cursor is in the 4th line meaning under line of python 50 and i copy this whole input to console, the program works fine.But i don't have to push enter to finish the input.It automatically gives correct output.
In both the cases, netbeans works fine.But i have to push enter after copying input to console to which is normal for any input.
what is the problem here?

Comment: If you don't end the line, it doesn't know that the number is finished. It could be `50000000000....`, and the stream is just blocked waiting for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netbeans may be automatically inserting a linebreak or whitespace when you press enter, where as intelliJ may be stripping the final one, and treating it as 'send to terminal'

There is no problem, just different terminals acting differently.

Comment: Yeah..netbeans takes the final enter as a newline which is considered as an input, but intelliJ does nothing of this sort.That's why this fuss.